# Как можно добавить динамически значения в обьект

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Стоит задача что нужно создать 3 обьект `['questionGroup', 'answer', 'question']` у каждого которого будет 2 значения `['single', 'multiple']`. 
Проблема в том что в каждый массив может быть добавленно какое то новое значение, тоесть сделать нужно это динамически. Результат пытаюсь получить чтобы было

```
questionGroup = {
   single: {...},
   multiple: {...}
},
answer = {
  single: {...},
  multiple: {...}
}
...
```

Вот мой код

```
const viewTypeArr = ['questionGroup', 'answer', 'question'];
const pageTypeArr = ['single', 'multiple'];

viewTypeArr.forEach((viewType) => {
            pageTypeArr.forEach((pageType) => {
                let itemsArr = [Какоето значение];

                state[viewType] = {
                    [pageType]: itemsArr,
                };
            });
        });
```

Но проблема что он пепезаписывает single и там остаёться только multiple, как можно это поправить, сейчас получаеться вот так

```
questionGroup = {
       multiple: {...}
    },
    answer = {
      multiple: {...}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запись

```
state[viewType] = {
   [pageType]: itemsArr,
};
```

при каждой итерации по `pageTypeArr` создает новый объект.

Соответственно, создание объекта надо вынести за цикл по `pageTypeArr`.

```js
const viewTypeArr = ['questionGroup', 'answer', 'question'];
const pageTypeArr = ['single', 'multiple'];
const state = {};
viewTypeArr.forEach((viewType) => {
  state[viewType] = {};
  pageTypeArr.forEach((pageType) => {
    let itemsArr = ['Какоето значение'];

    state[viewType][pageType] = itemsArr;
  });
});

console.log(state);
```